# How can I create a dummy DB for developer? (original has many tables and values like decimal int text)

Tags: database, mysql, data-recovery

I want to optimize my SQL queries, which run too slow on my production DB.
To do this efficiently, I was suggested to give access to the SQL developer.
The information on the DB is commercially sensitive.

So I thought about duplicating it to a new user on the server, and then somehow change all the values from the real ones, into dummy ones.

However, this involves perhaps about 20 tables, and each of them has different input such as Text, INT, Date, Etc.

Is there any easy way for me to achieve this? or any other solution to avoid this data exposure.

Comment: There are tools and methods to produce an arguably anonymized version of a database (some anonymizations are better than others). However even if you did this, would you really want to turn the changes loose on your production system without having fully tested it against actual data? I think you need a *trusted* *developer* who can work with a full copy of the operational data. An untrusted developer using altered data would not be my choice.

Comment: What is true is they need the same type and scale of data -- similar number of rows, similar lengths for variable-text, similar variations in values.  Optimizing 1,000 row tables is different from 1,000,000 row tables.

Comment: @user10216038: Sorry, no. You don't put a **copy** of highly sensitive data anywhere to use for development. I sure as hell don't want Joe SQL having access to my health or financial information to play around with during development, or being in an area that isn't kept as secure as production data would be. If your company allows that, please let us know where you work, especially if you're located in the US or EU; there are major laws being violated.

Comment: There are a number of techniques that can be used by a sql developer that does not have the underlying data, the result is poorer without an actual system to test on but can fix performance shortcomings from the original app/database. A simple desk check of the database and sql queries might identify easy fixes. PK and FK Indexes, query issues, query pagination, memory usage, system utilization sizing etc.

Comment: what is some good, user friendly tool? I'm running it on Apache server.